# Operator << with virtual classes

Tags: c++

i have a problem. I have a class logic, with a string and an object. I want that when i write `cout<<a` in the logic class, this operator changes my string. So i did this:

logic.h

```
class logic
{
private:
int str;
A a;
public:
...
};
```

logic.cpp

```
...
...
cout<<*a;
...

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& A)
{
    int=a.num;
    return os;
}
```

z.h

```
class Z
{
public:
virtual Z* aa();
...
};
```

a.h

```
class A: public Z
{
private:
int num;
public:
virtual Z* aa();
...
};
```

And i got these errors:

> expected class-name before '{' token (`on class A:public Z {` ) ISO
>   C++ forbids declaration of 'Z' with no type, 'Z' declared as a
>   'virtual' field, expected ';' before '*' token (on every virtual
>   function in A)

Can you help me?

Comment: Well, you can't inherit a class that doesn't exist. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a semicolon after the class definition:

```
class A: public Z
{
private:
  int num;
  public:
  virtual Z* aa();
  // ...
}; // <-- SEMICOLON!!1
```

Also, make sure that `Z` is defined *before* `A` is defined, by `#include`ing `z.h` in `a.h`.

Comment: @AsAs you also need a semicolon after the definition of `Z`, of course.

Comment: expected class-name before '{' token **(on class A:public Z { )** ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Z' with no type, 'Z' declared as a 'virtual' field, expected ';' before '*' token **(on every virtual function in A)**. By the way, what should write after the class? I got these errors just because i added the << operand. Without it everything work.

Comment: You need a semicolon after each class definition. Besides the missing semicolons, the code you posted is fine. Oh, and you also need to put `cout<<*a;` in a function.

Comment: Sorry but it's the first time that i heard of semicolon. The code worked just fine before i added the <<. What should i add?

Comment: No, it's not there. See your question.

Comment: @AsAs: No, there isn't. You must have a semicolon after the close brace of every class. You have one after the close brace of your class `logic`, but not for class `A` or class `Z`.

Comment: @AsAs please post your complete code [here](http://ideone.com), manually including the header files and leaving out the `#include` directives.

Comment: `#ifndef OPERAND_H
#define OPERAND_H
#include "calculator.h"

using std::string;

class Operand
{
public:
    virtual Operand* AddC(Operand* op2)=0;
    virtual Operand* SubtractC(Operand* op2)=0;
    virtual Operand* MultiplyC(Operand* op2)=0;
    virtual Operand* DivideC(Operand* op2)=0;
    virtual Operand* Conjugation()=0;
    virtual Operand* Reciprocal()=0;
    virtual ~Operand();
};

#endif // OPERAND_H
`

Comment: `#ifndef COMPLEX_H
#define COMPLEX_H
#include "calculator.h"
#include <string>
#include <operand.h>
using std::string;
class Complex : public Operand
{
public:
    Complex(double aa, double bb);
    virtual ~Complex();
    double GetA() const;
    double GetB() const;
    virtual Operand* mix(Operand* op2);
    virtual Operand* AddC(Operand *op2);
    virtual Operand* SubtractC(Operand* op2);
    virtual Operand* MultiplyC(Operand* op2);
    virtual Operand* DivideC(Operand* op2);
virtual Operand* Conjugation();
virtual Operand* Reciprocal();
private:
    double a, b;
};
#endif // COMPLEX_H`

Comment: in calculator there is a string named print and:
`Operand* Calculator::Add(Operand* o1, operand* op2)
{
...
op=op1+op2;
...
cout<<*op;
}`

`ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Complex& c)
{
    stringstream ss;
    if (b>=0)
        ss<<c.GetA()<<"+"<<c.GetB()<<"i";
    else
        ss<<c.GetA()<<c.GetB()<<"i";
    print=ss.str();
    return os;
}`